# when using matplotlib with ipython notebook plt.show() function doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I launched the ipython notebook using:

```
$ ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

in the command prompt.

when running this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot([1,2,3])
```

it automatically plots the graph without having to use the plt.show() function, however I find that the plt.show function doesn't work for me, or some other functions like plt.legend().

Does anybody know why this is happening, or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The plt.show() doesn't do anything because when you activate the --pylab mode the matplotlib is executed in the interactive mode, which display even without using show().

About the legend, what do you mean it doesn't work? if you obtain an error like "No labeled objects found" it's because in the line code that you show you haven't set the label parameter to the plot

Answer (score 0):

As said, you do not need to import pyplot.
Try:

```
fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot([1,2,3])
```

Then:

```
ax1.legend(('hello',))
fig.show()
```

will plot the figure with a legend.
Using Ipython is very easy to look at the hints-docs and the available properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is there a way that i can launch ipython so that it only plots when I use the plt.plot() function?

Comment: @SeanGeoffreyPietz if you launch without `inline`, figures only appear in a separate interactive window and only when you `show()` (eg: just `--pylab` on the ipython command line or `from pylab import *` within your notebook). Be sure you have a GUI backend for matplotlib, or nothing appears. (google `matplotlibrc` and "backend" to find out how)